# How to style selection handles in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I have a TextInput and want to style the selection handles, i already have the `selectionColor` prop set but this does not style the handles, any fixes?

I already read [this issue on react-native's repo](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30283) but it does not seem it has fixed anything

[image]
[image]

I am using `React: 0.73.4` and Expo `50.0.8`